# Specify AutoCompleteTextView Adapter in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

Almost getting it running.
So I have my static PlaceholderFragment that looks like this:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.customer);
        String[] customers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.al_customers);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, customers);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

So my problem is this row:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'ArraAdapter(com.g.h.MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment,int,java.lang.String[])'
```

I did try to put a class in front of "this":

```
MainActivity.this
```

Comment: What happened when you did `MainActivity.this`?

Comment: use getActivity() to replace this

Comment: getActivity made the magic. Awesome

Answer (score 2):

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_type_pres);
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>( getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mylist));
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer given by Nolly J in comment:

> "use getActivity() to replace this"

And it worked like magic.